# How to dismiss an alertbox?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, onpause

I want to dismiss my alert-box from my onPause() method because, I am checking the internet connection and if no connection is there I am showing an alert-box saying no connection. But when I minimize the app and relaunch it the previous alert-box is present there so in total two alert-boxes will be there I want to avoid that.So if I am dismissing it in the onPause() method  the second one will not come up.

Can anybody help me with this, Thank you.

```
   if (!haveNetworkConnection) {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Connection",
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            advtlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            System.out.println("no network");
            showGraphOverlay();
            hideOutputTextView();
            hideProgressBar();
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    InterPreterWithAnimation.this);

            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("No Network");

            // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog.setMessage("Turn on Wifi or Mobile data");

            // Setting Icon to Dialog
            // alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.);

            // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {

                            // Write your code here to invoke YES event

                            InterPreterWithAnimation.this
                                    .startActivity(new Intent(
                                            Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));

                        }
                    });

            // Setting Negative "NO" Button
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            // Write your code here to invoke NO event
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            // Showing Alert Message
            alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: use dialog,cancel() method.

Comment: Try this way `if (dialog.isShowing()) dialog.dismiss();`

Comment: Use `dialog.dismiss()`

Comment: Make alertDialog a global class member and dismiss/reuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating `AlertDialog` this way:

```
        AlertDialog.Builder mAlertDialogBuilder = new Builder(mContext);
        mAlertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your title here...");
        mAlertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Your message here...");
        mAlertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                    }
                });

        mAlertDialog = mAlertDialogBuilder.create();
        mAlertDialog.show();
```

Then, you can dismiss inside `onPause()` as:

```
if(mAlertDialog.isShowing())
{
    mAlertDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Also, declare your `AlertDialog` variable as your class member.

Comment: The method create() is undefined for the type mAlertDialogBuilder its showing like this;

Comment: @sunilsunny are you sure ? Did you wrote this `AlertDialog.Builder mAlertDialogBuilder = new Builder(mContext);` as this is the code i am currently using.

Comment: Actually i have a doubt what is this mAlertDialog  variable     private AlertDialog mAlertDialog; I declared like this globally .Sorry I am new to Android that's why...

Comment: @sunilsunny Yes. You are right. Its a reference of `AlertDialog` created inside your Activity class

Comment: K now all the errors are gone but now it's not showing the alertbox

Comment: @sunilsunny Please update your question with last tried code and post the whole activity code.

Answer (score 2):

First defined `AlertDialog.Builder builder` Globally and try to check `dialog` object `dialog!=null` in `onPause()` and then

```
if (dialog.isShowing()) {
 dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Did you go through my code..? I am using an AlertDialog.Builder.

Comment: defined `final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog` Globally and try.

Comment: Its showing an error actually this dialog is an DialogInterface variable right?

Answer (score 1):

Create global object of AlertDialog and then call `dialog.dismiss()` in `onPause()` method if dialog is already showing

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance variable in the class

```
private AlertDialog alertDialog;
```

And then use the following code for displaying the Alert.

```
alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this)
    .setTitle("Title");
    .setMessage("Message")
[...]
    .show();
```

Then in the onPause you can dismiss the `alertDialog` using the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (alertDialog != null) {
        alertDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: alertDialog.dismiss();is showing error.This alertDialog is an object of AlertDialog.Builder and I think dismiss is not available in that only show is available.

Comment: The method Builder(MyActivity) is undefined for the type AlertDialog its showing this error.

Comment: Use InterPreterWithAnimation.this instead of MyActivity.

Comment: ya I actually used that.. :)

Comment: Thanks I got the answer I think you and shree202 was saying the same thing... Thanks anyway..

Answer (score 0):

**First:** create **AlertDialog** instance so that it can access from any where in that class as follows...

```
private AlertDialog mNetworkConnectionDialog = null;

@Override
    protected void onCreateActivity(Bundle savedInstanceState){
```

**Second:** you didn't put **@Override** notation before **onClick** method. And instead of **alertDialog.show();** you should pass your **alertDialog** to **mNetworkConnectionDialog** by creating as follows...

```
mNetworkConnectionDialog = alertDialog.create();
```

Instead of passing **InterPreterWithAnimation.this** into AlertDialog.Builder constructor you can also pass only **this**. Here, I'm giving the corrected version of code...

```
if (!haveNetworkConnection) {
    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Connection",
    // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    advtlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    System.out.println("no network");
    showGraphOverlay();
    hideOutputTextView();
    hideProgressBar();

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
          InterPreterWithAnimation.this);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("No Network");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("Turn on Wifi or Mobile data");

    // Setting Icon to Dialog
    // alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.);

    // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    // Write your code here to invoke YES event

                    InterPreterWithAnimation.this.startActivity(new Intent(
                                            Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

    // Setting Negative "NO" Button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Ok",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    // Write your code here to invoke NO event
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });


    // Showing Alert Message
    mNetworkConnectionDialog = alertDialog.create();
    mNetworkConnectionDialog.show();
}
```

**Third:** Since you want dismiss your dialog when **onPause** method called then you should write mNetworkConnectionDialog.dismiss(); as follows...

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (mNetworkConnectionDialog != null) {
        mNetworkConnectionDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```